# Understanding steps of a proof of a positive matrix being symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In the solution it's previously proven through weak formulation theorem that if we can show
$<Px,x>=<P^*x,x>$, then a positive matrix is symmetric.

Here is the written proof. We assume that $A$ is a positive matrix.

$<Ax,x>=(Ax)^*x$

$=((Ax)^*x)^*$

$=x^*(Ax)$

$=<x,Ax>$

$=<A^*x,x>$

I have two basic questions about the steps:

I don't understand the first step $<Ax,x>=(Ax)^*x$. How do we end up there?

My second question is is on the second line where it's stated that $(Ax)^*x=((Ax)^*x)^*$. Is this a property of symmetric matrices and why aren't the $x$:es affected by this?

Answer (score 1):

1. $<Ax,x>=(Ax)^*x$ is the definition of the inner product for two vectors $<x,y> = x^* y$
2. $(Ax)^* x$ is a number so that is why is equal to it transpose $(Ax)^*x=((Ax)^*x)^*$

Comment: The second one I now understand! The definition of the inner product I don't. The only definition which I have been taught is $<x,y>=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j^*$ and I think this would be equal to $xy^*$.

Comment: The inner product is a number so for two vectors has to be the multiplication between a row vector and a column vector $<x,y> = x^T y = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j y_j$ in the case of complex number the usual choice is to use the complex conjugate transpose $<x,y> = x^* y = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^* y_j$ [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)